# MSVCP120.dll missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I compiled and linked an executable file in VS2013, and then tried to run that exe on another computer.
I get this error on the other computer:

[image]

I read on this problem, and I saw I need to download VS2013 on the other computer to be able to execute this file.
But what is the point in exe file if I need to download a VS2013 on any computer I want to run it on? 
Is there any normal way to execute it through the visual without go through this problem?

Comment: have you tried to install the redist? Does it work now? Or do you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

The `MSVCP120.dll` is part of the [Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Download and install it on the other PCs to get the program working or link the required lib via static linking.