# Wampserver logo is not getting green- mysqld.exe-system error is showing

Tags: wampserver

while during installing it is showing that {mysqld.exe- system error}-in which it is written that THE CODE EXECUTION CANNOT PROCEED BECAUSE MSVCP120.DLL WAS NOT FOUND. REINSTALLING THE PROGRAM MAY FIX THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSVCP120.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468866/msvcp120-dll-missing)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the install of WAMPServer does is remind you to check that you have all the required MSVC Runtime libraries.

If you are not sure that you have evenything, go to the backup repo for WAMPServer here [Checks VC++ packages installed MD5](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and download the checker, run it, it will tell you what you are missing.

You can also find a full set of 32 and 64 bit runtime libraries on that site as well

[All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits) MD5](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

or

[All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits) MD5](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Download there, they are zip files, unzip whichever one you need and then run each of the library installs one at a time in a logical version number order starting at the oldest to the newest